# "Suspend" a workflow in .NET 4?

Tags: .net, workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, suspend

I've to do a small test application, I want to suspend the application.

I saw there is a "SuspendActivity" but I can't find it in .Net 4.0, so how I'm supposed to pause my workflow and resume it from my application?

It's for a single sample on which I've to display every step with a "next" button.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are looking for the new **Bookmarks** concept in WF 4.0.
Basically, you can create a custom activity that defines a bookmark, and when the workflow execution reaches this activity, the execution is suspended until you resume the bookmark.

Take a look into the section *Additional activity concepts* in [A Developer's Introduction to Windows Workflow Foundation (WF) in .NET 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342461.aspx)

It is a very good introuduction to WF 4.0. Hope it helps!